# How can I resize the images in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am using logo.png and if `width: 50` and `height: 50` (see screenshot_1) then only some part of the image is viewable on the entire image. Now if `width: 100` and `height: 50`(see screenshot_2) the entire image is seen but I want the entire image with small dimensions how can I do that? I tried different values of width and height but doesn't work?

Original image dimensions are: 50 X 26

Screenshot1:

[image]

Screenshot2:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a Property called resizeMode:'contain' in the image style and mention your width and height

```
<Image style={{width:'your_width',height:'your_height',resizeMode:'contain'}} />
```

Hope that helps